# Executing dism batch command from WIX installer

Tags: windows, batch-file, wix

I have created a WIX msi installer which executes a batch command using dism.exe to enable IIS windows features. When I execute the msi installer the executed command doesn't take effect and the desired windows features are not enabled also the control panel doesn't show that a new application is installed, but when I run the same msi installer using command line arguments:

```
msiexec /i BatchFileExecutor.msi /Lime logfile.txt
```

the desired windows features get enabled and the control panel shows that the application is installed.

Below is the WIX code that I am using:

```
<CustomAction Id="BatchCmd"
              Property="BatchRun"
              Value='"[WindowsFolder]Sysnative\dism.exe" /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:IIS-WebServerRole"' 
              Execute='immediate' 
              Return='check'>
</CustomAction>

<CustomAction Id="BatchRun" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="yes">
</CustomAction>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="BatchCmd" Before="BatchRun">NOT Installed</Custom>
  <Custom Action="BatchRun" After="InstallFiles">NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Is there some code fragment out of place or have I wrongly set some property?

Comment: Just clarifying here - is a batch file involved at all?

Comment: @foxidrive In the current code its not involved, I am directly running the batch command. But that was not my intention I was initially trying to run a batch file but was having issues with accessing the right path to run the dism.exe and while searching on Google found someones post who was running is his batch command this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The customaction value attribute doesn't seem to have the right number of "'s to me.  Note that QuietExecCA requires a full path wrapped in quotes for the EXE but I don't think there's any need for a " after the feature name.

Also you don't want impersonation for your deferred CA.  You want no impersonation so it runs elevated in the system context.

Finally I'd be sure to include switches that prevent DISM from forcing a reboot during the middle of your installation.  Some windows features take a reboot to become effective.   For this reason I put DISM commands as their own package inside of a bootstrapper bundle / chain outside of my MSI.